# Laravel 5: how to insert data in database and return field back

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

Sorry if it's a stupid question, but I am new in framework programming, and also in Laravel. I want to insert my data in a database and return `id` back, but in the database the field in the table is not `id`, but `owner_id`. How i can return it back? I'm using `PostgreSQL` and set it `auto-incrementing` ready.

This is my code:

```
    $regis = new ltd_owner;
    $regis->owner_name = $register['firstname'] . ' ' . $register['lastname'];
    $regis->represent_company_id = $register['isRepresent'];
    $regis->gender = $register['sex'];
    $regis->address_id = '7598';
    $regis->nationality_id = '24';
    $regis->save();
```

Please help me to fix it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a different primary key in your Model:

```
protected $primaryKey = "owner_id";
```

Then, after you do the `save()`, the field should be populated automatically, and you can access it:

```
var_dump($regis->owner_id);
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helpful.

Comment: `stackover flow` not allow me

Answer (score 0):

If you use different id name, you should define it in the Model.

Add the following line to the ltd_owner model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'owner_id';
```

Then if you create a new model, you can get back the id.

```
$regis = new ltd_owner;
$regis->owner_name = $register['firstname'] . ' ' . $register['lastname'];
$regis->represent_company_id = $register['isRepresent'];
$regis->gender = $register['sex'];
$regis->address_id = '7598';
$regis->nationality_id = '24';
$regis->save();
//inserted model id:
$regis->owner_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

After passing `$regis->save();` 
`$regis` will hold your new data.
You can get those variable by calling them `$regis->column_name` for example `$regis->owner_id;`, `$regis->address_id; $regis->gender`
Hope you understand what's happening